# Can the size of beta coefficients and t-values from a linear probability model be trusted?

Tags: regression, probability, regression-coefficients, binary-data, linear-probability-model

I have a series of predictors and want to see how each of them predicts a binary dependent variable that takes on the values of 1/0 (i.e., yes/no). I am running a series of linear probability models, each with a different predictor and the same covariates (`DV ~ predictor + age + gender`). This is all done in the same sample.

I know a logit model would be preferable for a binary outcome but I am not interested in correct classification. **I am interested in the betas and t-values associated with each of the predictors** so that I can compare them to each other and to the betas and t-values in a different series of (OLS) models done in the same sample.

Can the betas and t-values from such linear probability models be trusted and compared with each other? I only found [a paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11135-014-0057-0) that explains that the size of linear probability model coefficients cannot be compared *across groups*, although the direction and significance of these coefficients can be trustworthy. Is my understanding correct that since in my case this is done within one group (albeit with different predictors), this problem does not apply to my case?

Comment: A simple search will rell you that due to the format of the model, you can get predicted probabilities outside of the unit interval ( [0,1]). In other words the model assumes that the probabilities can be below 1 and above 0. If you are okay with this assumption, you can interpretate as usual linear regression.

Comment: It also puzzles me a little that you say that you are only intrested in the cofficients (or betas as you call them) and use that as an argument not to use logistic regression. You can easily interpretate the coefficients in a logistic regression, they are just interpretated a little different. For your particular case I would probally use a posson regression (zou, 2004), where you can interpretate the coefficients either as a risk difference or changes in relative risk.

Comment: It seems you need to get bit more background knowledge about models before you continue with your problem

Comment: It depends on how you want to compare them.  It's perfectly legitimate to decide whether one beta exceeds another or not simply by examining their estimates.  The standard way to go further is to examine the two models nested within the model that includes *both* predictors.

Comment: @Kirsten thanks for your response! I understand how coefficients are interpreted in logistic regression. The problem is that I need coefficients that would be directly comparable to the coefficients I get in another series of models, which are OLS regressions. To add a bit of context, I am trying to see if any given predictor has a bigger effect on a dependent variable that is binary or on a dependent variable that is continuous. I cannot directly compare coefficients from a logistic regression with coefficients from a linear regression because they each mean a different thing, right?

Comment: @whuber thanks. I expect high collinearity in the predictors and am interested in the differential correlates of our predictors, i.e. in their individual effects. The question is if I can compare the size of the betas between models that are not nested but were run in the same sample.